# Swagger UI: specify responseInterceptor in swagger-config.yaml

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to use swagger-config.yaml to configure swagger UI as mentioned in the [document](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md).

The document mentions parameters like requestInterceptor or responseInterceptor, but they are all defined as a function. I don't think I can really put a function in yaml file per specification, and I have tried to put function in it as string but swagger ui won't pick it up.

My question is can I use requestInterceptor or responseInterceptor in the swagger-config.yaml file or these parameters cannot be used in config file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the `requestInerceptor` and `responseInterceptor` **cannot** be defined in the `swagger-config.yaml` file. They can only be defined in JavaScript:

```js
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  "dom_id": "#swagger-ui",
  deepLinking: true,
  ...
  requestInterceptor: function(req) {
    req.headers["MyCustomHeader"] = "value";
    return req;
  }
})
```